# no module named `numpy` in python 3.6 interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, ubuntu

I'm using `Python 3.6 v` in `Ubuntu 18.04LTS`. I installed `numpy` package using pip. When i used `Python 3.6` interpreter it throws

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' and for Python2.7
```

interpreter it didn't throws any error. Any suggestions will be very helpful. I searched in `google` and `github` nothing helped me.

Comment: Did you install `numpy` for python 2.7 rather than for python 3.6?

Comment: i installed for python3.6

Comment: I have to use `pip3` not `pip`.

Comment: how do you know that you are using python3.6 ? how do you know that you installed your package in python3.6 path? did you use pip or pip3 ?

Comment: @ThalishSajeed i changed alias in ubuntu for python=python3.6.

Comment: on your terminal -

`python --version` again next command
`pip -V`

post the output

Comment: pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Comment: post both outputs please

Comment: Python 2.7.15rc1. I recently removed that alias.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the outputs you posted -

your `pip` and `python` are pointing to version 2.7

if you try `pip install numpy` you will install into your python 2.7 env

if you start python interpreter by default you'll be starting python2.7 and you should be able to find `numpy` package installed.

if you want to do the same in `python3.xx` use `python3` , `pip3` or use
[virtual environments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Comment: sorry for mentioning late i used this in vitualenv of python3.6

Comment: well, in that case you probably did not activate your virtual env or your virtual env setup is incorrect. Because if you had a 3.6 python env setup your `pip -V` and `python --version` outputs should have reflected that - instead your output shows 2.7 python

Comment: thanks for the help. I'll take your guidance and check what gone wrong.